# How to make a button that accepts only .json type files on clicking submit with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, button, input

I'm creating a new page in the application that will be responsible for imports. I need an import button that only accepts files of type Json. I'm using Angular 6 (I'm very new to Angular and FE, I mostly did BE). Then I will send all the content of the .json into the DB either line by line either as a bulk.

Comment: show your research efforts & update your question according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve your goal by doing this

**accept=".json"**

```
<input type="file" accept=".json">
```

Comment: very precise answer. Good job bro